# Count в связке с group_by

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите почему такие неожиданные результаты выдает запрос?

Таблица user

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | admin |
+----+-------+
```

Таблица address

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | addrr |
+---------+-------+
|    1    | addr1 |
+---------+-------+
|    1    | addr2 |
+---------+-------+
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(user.id) AS count 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN address ON user.id = address.user_id 
WHERE user_id = 1 
GROUP BY user.id
[count] => 2
```

Почему count = 2 а не 1, GROUP BY же группирует все по идентификатору пользователя? Например, если запустить такой запрос:

```
SELECT user.id 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN address ON user.id = address.user_id 
WHERE user_id = 1 
GROUP BY user.id;
[id] => 1
```

То ожидаемо появится только один id. Если их этого запроса убрать GROUP BY, то  ответ без сюрпризов: `[id] => 1 [id] => 1`.

Если добавить DISTINCT, то все подсчитывается как и задумывалось:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user.id)) AS count 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN address ON user.id = address.user_id 
WHERE user_id = 1 
GROUP BY user.id
[count] => 1
```

Получается, что сначала подсчитывается COUNT() а только потом группируется с помощью GROUP BY?

Comment: Мне кажется вы привели неверные входные данные =) то что вы описали при таких входных данных нереально, а именно таблица `address` для такого поведения должна содержать обе записи с `user_id`=1. и тогда будет поведение описанное вами.

Comment: Первым происходит JOIN. и вот такое поведение: `Если их этого запроса убрать GROUP BY, то`(второй пример - после него текст) - невозможно для приведенных данных =) С другой стороны именно такое поведение будет если в `address` обе записи имеют `user_id=1`, именно тогда появляется необходимость в Group BY, и именно в таком случае первый запрос будет возвращать 2. собственно тогда всё описанное поведение станет - вполне по логике\феншую\документации =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков - вполне реально: все  запросы из моего вопроса протестированы. Если вам интересно, создайте 2 таблички и запустите запросы - займет 5 мин.

Comment: Смотрите ответ, если в комментариях вы меня не услышали, я вам написал **в каком случае описанное поведение возможно**, остальные ваши примеры сработают точно так же - только если входные данные будут как на третьем скриншоте.

Answer (score 0):

Простите за ответ скриншотами, но автора по другому убедить не выйдет, в комментариях я ему написал текстом =)

Мы с автором вопроса пришли к некому согласию по входным данным, теперь ответ на вопрос:

- Сначало происходит склейка таблиц(JOIN).
- Следом происходит группировка(Group By).
- После этого идет подсчет суммы\количества(SUM\COUNT) **внутри каждой группы**. Т.е. если у вас Group By сгруппировал 2 идиентичные записи (`user_id=1`) То COUNT - вернет количество сгруппированых в одну строку записей(т.е. в вашем случае 2 шт).

Group BY подавляет вывод, но не мешает подсчету удаленных из вывода данных.

Comment: Вы бы не могли изъясняться так, что бы то, что вы написали, было понятно не только вам? Что значит "поведение невозможно" - ни один из запросов в моем вопросе не вызывает ошибок, в чем заключается "невозможность"? Здесь приведены только необходимые для примера колонки и основная часть запроса - та, которая вызывает возврат неожиданного результата при использовании COUNT + GROUP BY. В реальном запросе еще много-много JOIN-ов, но неожиданный результат возникает только при присоединении таблицы с отношением один ко многим, когда в ней по одному ID может быть найдено несколько строк.

Comment: @Miron Посмотрите скриншоты, первый\третий скрин - входные данне. Второй четвертый - результат вашего запроса. Я вам под вашим вопросом в комментарии написал в каком случае ваши SQL запросы будут давать такие результаты(как вы получаете), если в таблице `address` будет 2 записи с `group_id = 1` и такие результаты(как у вас) в таком случае - документированное поведение. У вас в примерах вопроса **неверно предоставлены входные данные в таблице address**

Comment: Владимир Клыков, так бы сразу и написали про ошибку в данных тестовой таблицы - спасибо, исправил. Только не group_id а user_id.

Comment: @Miron  Так вы прочитайте первый же комментарий под вашим вопросом =) там так и написано что во входных данных - ошибка. И если это так - подсчет COUNT просисходит внутри группы, и это нормальное поведение, так и должно быть.